# Code generated with LLVM-IR segfaults at runtime

Tags: segmentation-fault, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

I am at the process of writing a toy compiler and I use llvm 10 as a backend for it. One of the features that I want to have is a linked list type just like functional programming. The IR I supply below is generated from my compiler,

I can't give you the code because its a few thousand lines and it's written in rust. I compiled llvm with assertion so I don't think the problem is there. I am pretty sure I generate some kind of weird return value since the program segfaults only when I return a list_type.

This code mallocs allot and it does not free any data. That's because I will change it later to use a garbage collector, that is also not the problem.

The question is can you find the reason it segfaults at runtime? It is also possible for me to supply a windows executable it someone want it.

```
def main():
            list[int] j
            int i 
            def list[int] test():
                list[int] j
                j := 5 # j
                j := 10 # j
                return j
            end
            j := test()
            i := head(j)
            puti(head(j))
        end
```

the generated LLVM-IR code is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/G7AEm3)

Comment: I don't care to chase links to read dependencies outside the question, or debug many thousands of lines. But I can guess what I'd say: "the verifier would catch this". Use [the verifier](https://llvm.org/doxygen/Verifier_8h.html) often. If that doesn't help, "emit debug information, debug information is helpful for debugging".

Comment: @arnt thank you the verifier pointed me to the right direction. I was generating double return type, one good and 1 bad due to old code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thanks to @arnt. I was basically generating wrong llvm-ir because I was creating 2 return instructions one after another. That lead llvm to undefined behavior, so I would suggest using the [verifier](https://llvm.org/doxygen/Verifier_8h.html) that comes with llvm to check the integrity of the generated code before compiling.